# How to match, merge and create a new array with php

Tags: php, arrays

This is new for me(and arrays are not my kind of thing), but not sure if this is possible as I could not find anything examples online but I have 2 arrays with data, and these arrays contain a value called 'slug', which have to merge/combined(category/product). These slugs need to match with the value called 'language' so that we can build a new array with these new values.

// first array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => de
        [translation] => blanko
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => en
        [translation] => white
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => es
        [translation] => blanco
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => fr
        [translation] => vierges
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => it
        [translation] => bianche
    )
)
```

// second array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => de
        [translation] => ettiketten-xxx
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => en
        [translation] => labels-xxxx
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => es
        [translation] => etiquetas-xxxx
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => fr
        [translation] => etiquettes-xxx
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 5
        [attribute] => slug
        [language] => it
        [translation] => etichette-xxxx
    )
)
```

I want to make a new array like

```
array(
   'de' => 'blanko/ettiketten-xxx',
   'fr' => 'vierges/etiquettes-xxx'
    // and so on
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a naive example of how to iterate through these and compile a third array with your desired values:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    foreach ($products as $product){
        if ($category['language'] == $product['language']){
            $translationString = $category['translation']."/".$product['translation'];
            $result[$category['language']] = $translationString;
        }
    }
}

echo print_r($result);
```

This will give you an array like:

```
Array(
   'de' => 'blanko/ettiketten-xxx',
   'en' => 'white/labels-xxxx',
   'es' => 'blanco/etiquetas-xxxx,
   'fr' => 'vierges/etiquettes-xxx'
)
```

You won't win any points for style though, there is probably a better way to do this using `array_map` or `array_walk` so maybe something to have a look at if you need to scale out